# creating something more reusable

Tags: jquery

I have the following which i seem to be repeating a lot of the same code.

```
        $('.announcementsTitle1').prepend(response.posts.data[0].name);
        $('.announcementsTitle2').prepend(response.posts.data[1].name);
        $('.announcementsTitle3').prepend(response.posts.data[2].name);
        $('.announcementsTitle4').prepend(response.posts.data[3].name);
        $('.announcementsTitle5').prepend(response.posts.data[4].name);

        $('.announcementsText1').prepend(response.posts.data[0].message);
        $('.announcementsText2').prepend(response.posts.data[1].message);
        $('.announcementsText3').prepend(response.posts.data[2].message);
        $('.announcementsText4').prepend(response.posts.data[3].message);
        $('.announcementsText5').prepend(response.posts.data[4].message);

        $('.announcementsText1').append(response.posts.data[0].description);
        $('.announcementsText2').append(response.posts.data[1].description);
        $('.announcementsText3').append(response.posts.data[2].description);
        $('.announcementsText4').append(response.posts.data[3].description);
        $('.announcementsText5').append(response.posts.data[4].description);

        $('.announcementsImage1').attr("src",response.posts.data[0].full_picture);
        $('.announcementsImage2').attr("src",response.posts.data[1].full_picture);
        $('.announcementsImage3').attr("src",response.posts.data[2].full_picture);
        $('.announcementsImage4').attr("src",response.posts.data[3].full_picture);
        $('.announcementsImage5').attr("src",response.posts.data[4].full_picture);]
```

Is there a way i could refactor something like this?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the HTML.

Comment: Great thanks ! Never really looked into loops !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery.each

```
   $.each(response.posts.data, function(index){

        $('.announcementsTitle'+index).prepend($(this).name);
        $('.announcementsText'+index).prepend($(this).message);
        $('.announcementsText'+index).prepend($(this).description);
        $('.announcementsImage'+index).attr("src",$(this).full_picture);

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop?

```
for (i=0;i<=4;i++) {
    $('.announcementsTitle'+(i+1)).prepend(response.posts.data[i].name);
    $('.announcementsText'+(i+1)).prepend(response.posts.data[i].message);
    $('.announcementsText'+(i+1)).append(response.posts.data[i].description);
    $('.announcementsImage'+(i+1)).attr("src",response.posts.data[i].full_picture);
}
```

Comment: Great thanks ! Never really looked into loops !